# Proof of existence and uniqueness of inverse of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inverse, operator-algebras

> **Theorem-1**
> If for a given operator $A$, both left inverse $A_l^{-1}$ and right inverse $A_r^{-1}$ exists, they are unique and identical.
> **Proof** -
> $A_l^{-1}=A_l^{-1}I=A_l^{-1}(AA_r^{-1})=(A_l^{-1}A)A_r^{-1}=IA_r^{-1}=A_r^{-1}$.
> Suppose there are two left inverses then they should be equal to the right inverse hence they are also equal.
> Similar argument for right inverse.

> **Theorem-2**
> If a linear operator $A$ has a uniques left inverse then its left inverse is also the (unique) right inverse.
> **Proof -**
> $A(A_l^{-1}A)=A$
> $\implies (AA_l^{-1})A=IA\tag{1}$
> $\implies (AA_l^{-1}-I)A=0=I-A_l^{-1}A$.
> $\implies (AA_l^{-1}-I+A_l^{-1})A=I$
> So, $AA_l^{-1}-I+A_l^{-1}=A_l^{-1}$.
> $\implies AA_l^{-1}=I$.
> Thus $A_l^{-1}$ is the right inverse of $A$ and by Theorem-1, it is unique.

I am thinking of proving Theorem-2 in another way.
We have $(AA_l^{-1})A=IA$.
$\implies AA_l^{-1}=I$.
Thus $A_l^{-1}$ is the right inverse of $A$ and by Theorem-1, it is unique.

Instead of the long proof to Theorem-2 we can directly prove it this way.
Am I correct in doing so or have I missed something in my proof?

Comment: There is no reason why left-invertible operators are right-invertible, or vice versa.  So you can't just go ahead and cancel the $A$ on the right from $CA=DA$ to $C=D$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, we can't directly say that if $CA=DA$, then $C=D$